# Unable to call removeEventListener from function

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have the following function below where I want to store all of my EventListeners related to UI behaviors.

I am currently able to add new events without problem but I cannot remove them since the reference to the function is completely lost.

I believe I may have to use .bind(this) or handleEvent but I cannot figure out if what I wrote is simply unable to achieve such goal without starting from scratch.

Basically I call the function like this and would like to keep it this way if possible:

addEventListener : `getUIbehaviour('scroll-hide-commentbox', 'add');`

removeEventListener : `getUIbehaviour('scroll-hide-commentbox', 'remove');`

Thank you for your help,

```
const pathfinder = (obj, path) =>
{
  let current=obj;
  path.split('.').forEach(function(p){ current = current[p]; });
  return current;
};


const getUIbehaviour = (type, action) =>
{

 let behaviours =
{
    'classic-product-search':
    {
        behaviour: function()
        {

            if (window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Desktop')
            {
                document.querySelector('#product-search').focus();
                window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
                document.querySelector('#product-search').value = '';
            }
            else if(window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Mobile') /* hide #products-ui on #product-search focus */
            {
                document.querySelector('#product-search').focus();
                document.querySelector('#products-ui').setAttribute('class', 'list noselect hidden');
                window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
                document.querySelector('#product-search').value = '';
            }

        },

        add : function()
        {
            document.querySelector('#product-search').addEventListener('focusin', this.behaviour, false);
        },

        remove : function()
        {
            document.querySelector('#product-search').removeEventListener('focusin', this.behaviour, false);
        }

    },

    'scroll-hide-commentbox':
    {
        behaviour: function ()
        {

    console.log('scrolling');

            let commentbox = document.querySelector('#comments');

            if (commentbox != null)
            {
                commentbox.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');
            }

            if (document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0 && window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Desktop' && commentbox != null)
            {
                commentbox.setAttribute('class', 'block');
            }
            else if (window.pageYOffset === 0 && window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Mobile' && commentbox != null)
            {
                commentbox.setAttribute('class', 'block');
            }

        },

        add : function()
        {
         document.addEventListener('scroll', this.behaviour, false);
        },

        remove : function()
        {
         document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.behaviour, false);
        }
    }

};

 let behaviour = pathfinder(behaviours, type);

 if (action ==='add')
 {
   return behaviour.add();
 }
 else if (action ==='remove')
 {
   return behaviour.remove();
 }

 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is simple move out object `behaviours` from function `getUIbehaviour`.

The problem is each time when you invoke `getUIbehaviour` function it creates new `behaviours` object

Short **current** version:

```
    const pathfinder = (obj, path) => {}; 
    const getUIbehaviour = (type, action) => {
      // Move out from scope
      let behaviours = {};
    };
```

Short **working** version:

```
    const pathfinder = (obj, path) => {};
    let behaviours = {}; 
    const getUIbehaviour = (type, action) => {};
```

Here is a link https://gist.github.com/andrey-ponamarev/392ee55337c3716ff3a55177289bdb7e

Comment: Well you just made my day, this is 100% working and I can now call this everywhere in my code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A quick alternative in your case would be to move `behaviour` into named functions, like below:

```
const pathfinder = (obj, path) => {
    let current=obj;
    path.split('.').forEach(function(p){ current = current[p]; });
    return current;
};


const getUIbehaviour = (type, action) => {

    function classicProductSearchBehavior() {
        if (window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Desktop') {
            document.querySelector('#product-search').focus();
            window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
            document.querySelector('#product-search').value = '';
        } else if(window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Mobile') /* hide #products-ui on #product-search focus */ {
            document.querySelector('#product-search').focus();
            document.querySelector('#products-ui').setAttribute('class', 'list noselect hidden');
            window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
            document.querySelector('#product-search').value = '';
        }
    }

    function showHideCommentbox() {
        console.log('scrolling');

        let commentbox = document.querySelector('#comments');

        if (commentbox != null) {
            commentbox.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');
        }

        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0 && window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Desktop' && commentbox != null) {
            commentbox.setAttribute('class', 'block');
        } else if (window.pageYOffset === 0 && window.GLOBAL.agent === 'Mobile' && commentbox != null) {
            commentbox.setAttribute('class', 'block');
        }
    }

    let behaviours = {
        'classic-product-search': {
            behaviour: classicProductSearchBehavior,
            add: function() {
                document.querySelector('#product-search').addEventListener('focusin', classicProductSearchBehavior, false);
            },
            remove : function() {
                document.querySelector('#product-search').removeEventListener('focusin', classicProductSearchBehavior, false);
            }
        },

        'scroll-hide-commentbox': {
            behaviour: showHideCommentbox,
            add : function() {
                document.addEventListener('scroll', showHideCommentbox, false);
            },
            remove : function() {
                document.removeEventListener('scroll', showHideCommentbox, false);
            }
        }
    };

    let behaviour = pathfinder(behaviours, type);

    if (action ==='add') {
        return behaviour.add();
    } else if (action ==='remove') {
        return behaviour.remove();
    }
};
```

Comment: I just tried your version I still can't remove the scrolling event, its as if its create a new instance of showHideCommentbox() and cannot unregister the original. Thank you for your input, I will keep digging..